# flex fill rect with many colors and rotation 45 degrees

Tags: apache-flex, colors, fill, rect

Is there are any way to fill s:Rect with 3-4 different colors and rotation 45 degrees? Something like:

```
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor  color="#ff0000" />
        <s:SolidColor  color="#00ff00" />
        <s:SolidColor  color="#ffff00" />
    </s:fill>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [LinearGradient](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/graphics/LinearGradient.html) as the `fill` property, like so:

```
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:LinearGradient rotation="45">
            <s:GradientEntry color="#ff0000" />
            <s:GradientEntry color="#00ff00" />
            <s:GradientEntry color="#ffff00" />
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

Comment: var lg:LinearGradient=new LinearGradient; lg.rotation=45; lg.entries=[new GradientEntry(0xff0000),new GradientEntry(0x00ff00)];

Comment: after this LinearGradient is only black.

Comment: @user3094544 Why would you want to write this in ActionScript? Did you assign `lg` to the Rect's `fill` property?

Answer (score 0):

iF you want in mxml then @RIA star is correct but if you want in action script here is the code. Its quite long but you can reduce it

```
protected function box1_mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(event.currentTarget!=null)
            {
                if(event.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER)
                {
                    var fill:LinearGradient = new LinearGradient();

                    var g1:GradientEntry = new GradientEntry(0xE7E7E7);
                    var g2:GradientEntry = new GradientEntry(0xFDFDFD);

                    fill.entries = [g1,g2];
                    fill.rotation = 45;
                    event.currentTarget.backgroundFill = fill;
                    Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.BUTTON;
                }
                else
                {
                    var fill1:LinearGradient = new LinearGradient();

                    var g3:GradientEntry = new GradientEntry(0xFDFDFD);
                    var g4:GradientEntry = new GradientEntry(0xE7E7E7);

                    fill1.entries = [g3,g4];
                    fill1.rotation = 45;
                    event.currentTarget.backgroundFill = fill1;
                    Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.AUTO;
                }
            }
        }
```